# Email user nickname displayed in parenthesis - eg. name@domain.com (Nickname)

Tags: wordpress, email, settings, cpanel, email-client

A client of mine has an email address with an unwanted nickname that displays in email recipient inboxes. The nickname is actually tied to an old domain he used to use, but there's no way I can see how these old and new data points ever connected to make this (nickname) appear.

I manage a website (WP + Cpanel + Hosting) for a client.

This client's email address is tied to a domain, but he has this nickname attached to his emails (when received in my own inboxes via Mac Mail + Gmail, and I can't find it published anywhere.

For example, this (Nickname) is nowhere to be found in the Cpanel or in Webmail (his original email client).

I don't know how to remove this but I really need it gone.